# magento 1.9.0 payment method payumoney is not working

Tags: php, integration, magento-1.9, payumoney

I have installed magento 1.9 with payment method PayUMoney.

PayUMoney provides the **merchant id** and **salt** after successful account creation on their site.

In magento admin payment method this **merchant id** and **salt** is submitted but when I go to use payment using PayUMoney it will return error- ***Sorry, Some Problem Occurred.***.

Can somebody help me to integrating the PayUMoney in Magento ?

Answer (score 2):

@IRSHAD  **Use the alphanumeric merchant key instead of numeric merchant ID to resolve the issue**. 
I too got this same Error. i contact **PayUMoney** regarding this error they said merchant id is the merchant key. Its wrongly mention in **PayUMoney** magneto extension.